# Sera que puedo hacer en mi query un SELECT con un rango de fecha segun el mes en curso

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente query:

```
$analisis = "SELECT usuario, users.nombre AS 'nombre', users.email AS 
                    'email', SUM(monto) AS 'monto_total', 
                     COUNT( usuario ) AS 'num'
             FROM pedidos 
             INNER JOIN users ON (pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario) 
             WHERE status_pedido = 'ENTREGADO'
             GROUP BY `usuario`, `monto`, nombre, email 
             ORDER BY num DESC
             LIMIT 0 , $limit_end";
```

Esta consulta me permite obtener una tabla con los siguientes datos:
`Usuario,   Nombre, Email,  Cantidad de Pedidos y el Total`
En la tabla **pedidos** tengo una columna de nombre **fecha** que es un timestamp quisiera saber si es posible filtrar los resultados por los correspondientes al mes en curso, tengo varias declaraciones de variables referentes a fechas que me permite para otras funciones ejecutar cosas en particular pero no logro atinar a darle la instrucción a mi query de que filtre también WHERE fecha sea igual al mes en curso.

```
$start = time();
$fecha_act = date("y-m-d H:i:s",$start);
$fads = strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y");
$fecha_actual_sistema = strftime("%Y/%m/%d");
$fecha_sistema = date("Y/m/d");
$dia = "";
$mes = strftime("%B");
$mes_de_pago_actual = strftime("%B/%Y");
$mes_fecha_sistema = date("m/Y");
```

Comment: Pregunta por mes y año, si sólo lo haces por mes te sacará el mismo mes de otros años, puedes hacerlo añadiendo esta condición al where: AND DATE_FORMAT(FECHA, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo directamente en la sentencia `mysql`, para ello utilizas `date_format` para comparar el año y mes de tu fecha con el año y mes de la fecha actual. Es necesario comparar año y mes para que traiga el presente mes de este año, si no traerá este mes para todos los años representados en la tabla.

```
"SELECT usuario, users.nombre AS 'nombre', users.email AS 
                    'email', SUM(monto) AS 'monto_total', 
                     COUNT( usuario ) AS 'num'
             FROM pedidos 
             INNER JOIN users ON (pedidos.usuario=users.idusuario) 
             WHERE status_pedido = 'ENTREGADO'
             AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
             GROUP BY `usuario`, `monto`, nombre, email 
             ORDER BY num DESC
             LIMIT 0 , $limit_end";
```

Comment: funciono pero me toco colocar en la linea que me indico hacerlo asi: `AND DATE_FORMAT(pedidos.fecha, '%Y%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')` Muchas gracias por su amable sugerencia..!